# How can I use JUnit's ExpectedException to check the state that's only on a child Exception?

Tags: java, junit, expected-exception

I'm trying to refactor this old code that does not use `ExpectedException` so that it *does* use it:

```
    try {
        //...
        fail();
    } catch (UniformInterfaceException e) {
        assertEquals(404, e.getResponse().getStatus());
        assertEquals("Could not find facility for aliasScope = DOESNTEXIST", e.getResponse().getEntity(String.class));
    }
```

And I can't figure out how to do this because I don't know how to check the value of `e.getResponse().getStatus()` or `e.getResponse().getEntity(String.class)` in an `ExpectedException`.  I do see that `ExpectedException` has an [expect](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html#expect%28org.hamcrest.Matcher%29) method that takes a hamcrest `Matcher`.  Maybe that's the key, but I'm not exactly sure how to use it.

How do I assert that the exception is in the state I want if that state only exists on the concrete exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "best" way is a custom matcher like the ones described here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/testing-custom-exceptions

So you would want something like this:

```
import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.junit.internal.matchers.TypeSafeMatcher;

public class UniformInterfaceExceptionMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<UniformInterfaceException> {

public static UniformInterfaceExceptionMatcher hasStatus(int status) {
    return new UniformInterfaceExceptionMatcher(status);
}

private int actualStatus, expectedStatus;

private UniformInterfaceExceptionMatcher(int expectedStatus) {
    this.expectedStatus = expectedStatus;
}

@Override
public boolean matchesSafely(final UniformInterfaceException exception) {
    actualStatus = exception.getResponse().getStatus();
    return expectedStatus == actualStatus;
}

@Override
public void describeTo(Description description) {
    description.appendValue(actualStatus)
            .appendText(" was found instead of ")
            .appendValue(expectedStatus);
}
```

}

then in your Test code:

```
@Test
public void someMethodThatThrowsCustomException() {
    expectedException.expect(UniformInterfaceException.class);
    expectedException.expect(UniformInterfaceExceptionMatcher.hasStatus(404));

    ....
}
```

Comment: There are A LOT of compilation errors in this.  But other than that, this works.  Is the first line of your `@Test` really necessary if I've got the second?  IE: Can I cut out `expectedException.expect(UniformInterfaceException.class);`?

Comment: @tieTYT sorry, I did a really quick and dirty write up without checking it in an IDE. All fixed now so it compiles.  It also looks like you can get rid of the `expect(UniformInterfaceException.class)` I think hamcrest will catch any exception (like the cast exception when hamcrest tries to call your matcher) and treat it as a failure.